# Drop one image into another image position

Tags: android

I am working on a project related to drag and drop.I have the drag code bleow.I want the drop code.

```
public class MprojectActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ImageView dragimage;                       
    private ImageView dropimage;                
    int x1,y1; 


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dragimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
        dragimage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        dropimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y = (int) event.getRawY();


        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            x1 = x - lParams.x;
            y1 = y - lParams.y;

        }


       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams(); 
            mParams.x = x-x1; 
            mParams.y = y-y1 ; 
            v.setLayoutParams(mParams);


             }   }

        }  
        return true;

        }

    }
```

Now If I drag the dragimage near to the dropimage I want to drop the dragimage into dropimage.I want to drop the dragimage only into the dropimage else the dragimage back to its position automatically.I need the drop code and also the position back code.

Comment: so, you want to put one image over another image.?

Answer (score 0):

**For Drag and Drop:**

Activity:

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


tv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

tv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/image" android:src="@drawable/image">
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_y="30dip" android:layout_x="118dip"
        android:layout_width="50sp" android:layout_height="50sp" android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/image1">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**For put image over another image:**

activity:

```
RelativeLayout rv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_ph);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
 ImageButton im1 = new ImageButton(this);

 im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lamp);
 im1.setId(i);
 im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tx.setText("lamp #" + v.getId());
}
 });

 params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
 params.leftMargin = x;
 params.topMargin = y;
 rv.addView(im1, params);
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/my_ph"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/map" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_below="@+id/image" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```